# How much is Aviation Stack Exchange involved in the moderation strike?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Are any ASE mods on strike? Are there any non-diamond users who used to actively check the review queues, use mod tools, VTC, etc., on strike other than myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those interested in such things, the situation which led to a call for a moderation strike have mostly been concluded: [Moderation strike: Conclusion and the way forward](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392032/moderation-strike-conclusion-and-the-way-forward)

Answer (score 7):

I am taking part, I've continued answering the odd question but no votes, no moderator action. This has been communicated to other mods, I don't expect it has really had much impact here.